Some styles of SVG ignored in PDF
I want to publish SVG pictures using styles cascading geometric transformations.
Here is an example of SVG with css-transform (with or without parameter):
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     style="stroke-width:10px;stroke:blue;"
     width="300"
     height="310"
     viewBox="0 -10 300 310">
  <style>
    :root {
      --paramT: 100px;
    }
    .translate {
     transform: translate(100px);
     stroke: green;
    }
    .variableTranslate {
      transform: translate(var(--paramT));
      stroke: red;
    }
  </style>
  <line x1="0" x2="100" y1="0"   y2="0" />
  <line x1="0" x2="100" y1="50"  y2="50"  style="stroke:orange;transform:translate(100px)"/>
  <line x1="0" x2="100" y1="100"  y2="100"  class="translate"/>
  <line x1="0" x2="100" y1="150" y2="150" class="variableTranslate" />
</svg>

In a browser, result is as expected:

Some styles related to transformations are ignored in the PDF of a document using this picture published with FOP:

Is it a limitation of FOP (only) ?

transform is a purely visual property, it doesn't actually affect layout.

From the FOP docs, it looks like transforms do work if they're part of SVG element's properties rather than CSS.
